# Creating a factory when base class is a class template

Tags: c++, templates, factory

Suppose I had a base class template, such as

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct BaseFoo {
  virtual int do_thing(T1 t1, T2 t2) = 0;
};
```

And a few derived classes that had different types for the template parameters, e.g.,

```
struct ThisFoo : public BaseFoo<int, float> {
  int do_thing(int i, float f) override;
};

struct ThatFoo : public BaseFoo<double, bool> {
  int do_thing(double d, bool b) override;
};
```

Can I create a factory that would let me instantiate one of the derived classes from a string at runtime, such as

```
std::string foo_type = "ThatFoo"; // perhaps from a config file
auto that_foo = Factory::create("ThatFoo");
```

Obviously a traditional factory doesn't work because every derived class has a base class with a different type.

Comment: How does the string contain the information that the compiler should base on when specialize the class in the instantiation process?

Comment: And the answer is most probably "no" from your question- The instantiation process done at compile-time and not at run-time. It will be "yes"  if you agree to instantiate all of the specialization possibilities ahead at compile-time, and just choose which one to use at run-time.

Comment: No you can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: The return type of `create` could be a union of all the possible return types. But then you have to figure out how client code can use that union. After all, the various types have nothing in common.

Comment: To have a factory like this, there would need to be a single common base for all your concrete (derived) classes.   A template class is not a single common base.

Comment: @KorelK Could you elaborate more on your comment about instantiating all the specialization possibilities and then choosing one? What would that look like?

Comment: You could have `Factory::create` return a `std::variant<ThisFoo, ThatFoo>` and then `std::visit` it.  The base template and `virtual` member function become unnecessary in this case.

Comment: If this is not an academic question and you are looking for a solution, then create an abstract base class with name "Base" and derive your BaseFoo from that. Then the createInstance function of the factory can return an ````std::unique_ptr```` to base